# Text overflow on Android in code box

Tags: bug, android-app, code-formatting

When you scroll right in the code box in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16033979), the text in the code box overflows.

Before and After:

[image: After]       [image: After]

**Device Information**

**Device** GT-I9505 (S4)

**Android Version** 5.0.1

**Application Version** 1.0.77

Comment: Your before and after pictures look the same to me.

Comment: Ah, I'm not sure why the links switched. Check now please?

Comment: Cool. Wasn't the downvote btw.
Reproduced on 4.4.4, app 1.0.78.